# Adwhirl for iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ads, adwhirl

I'm trying to integrate adWhirl into my iPad app, but I it's doesn't seem to work.
It seems like lot's of people encountered the same issue, but I couldn't find a remedy.
I tried to stretch the adView to fit the iPad screen, but the ad remains iPhone sized.

Is there a known solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires that you change each adapter that you would like to use.
I have written up a tutorial on how to do this with admob, iad, greystripe, and mdotm.

Take a look at it here: http://goosesoft.com/blog/universal-adwhirl-ads-in-cocos2d-2/

Edit: I have now also made a UIKit Universal Adwhirl tutorial found here: http://goosesoft.com/blog/universal-adwhirl-uikit/

Comment: That's cool. I just downloaded the app, how do you keep the ad always below ? is it the same UIViewController you're presenting, or that when I press "Controls" for instance you're using a navigation controller and you push a new controller (which in that case I'm not sure how do you keep using the same adWhirlView instance while keeping it on screen without the need to remove if from the first screen and add it to the second).

Comment: well first of all the this is made using using the cocos2d game engine. (http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/)  So the set up is going to have some differences. Notice how the ad view is a "layer" and not a viewcontroller, for instance. Neither am I using a navigation controller, but instead different menus that I am animating on and off the screen. I am sorry, I just saw the "Adwhirl for Ipad" and posted, but if you have not worked with cocos2d, you will have a hard time adapting it for a normal UIKit app.  I will work on another "UIKit Adwhirl On Ipad" tutorial today and keep you posted.

Comment: Cool, waiting to hear from you. Thanks